# Why the intrinsic entanglement in a topologically ordered state lowers the entanglement entropy?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, topological-order

The entanglement entropy of the topologically ordered state exhibits the universal additive constant to the area law: $$S \sim \alpha L^{d-1} - \gamma $$
The topologically ordered states are long-range entangled,
and thus I naively expect that the intrinsic entanglement enhance the entanglement entropy.
However, as written above, it reduces.
Maybe, I should follow literatures in details.
But, before that, if someone can give me an intuitive explanation, it would be highly appreciated.